# Installed magento 2.4.6-p1 & added a few products then tried to add a product to cart and got the below error. Any help will be much appreciated

Tags: addtocart

Installed magento 2.4.6-p1 added a few products and tried to add product to cart and got the below error. Any help will be much appreciated.

> [2023-08-07T02:38:55.058044+00:00] main.DEBUG: URI
> '/v246v1/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmVzdWlnZW5lcmlzLmNvbS92MjQ2djEvYi1jLWluc3BpcmUtZTE1MC5odG1s/product/1/''
> cannot be accessed with GET method
> (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add) [] []
> [2023-08-07T02:38:55.060439+00:00] main.DEBUG: Request validation
> failed for action "Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor"
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException(code: 0):
> Invalid request received at
> /home/bsgcom/public_html/v246v1/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"}
> []

Comment: Is there any custom module installed ? Or any custom theme / development ?

Comment: Yes a custom theme is installed

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below method to find out the cause:-

1. Please check in defult LUMA theme, You can change it from admin

> Admin -> Content -> Design -> Configuration

2. Disable all third-party modules related to the add-to-cart functionality.